# `terraform providers` command confusing resources for providers

Tags: plugins, terraform

I am learning to develop a terraform provider. I am following this amazing tutorial put together by hashicorp: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-use?in=terraform/providers#create-order

`Terraform init` worked when I added the `required_providers` block. However, once I added the the resource and do `terraform apply`, apply fails with "Could not load plugin" Error. Following this error, when I run `terraform providers` to debug, it listed both the provider and resource as as required providers.

Terraform version I am using: 0.13.5

Below is the code I used:

````
    required_providers {
      hashicups = {
          versions = ["0.3"]
          source = "hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups"
      }
    }
}

resource "haschicups_order" "edu" {
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 3
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 2
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
}

output "edu_order" {
  value = haschicups_order.edu
}```

```% terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups]
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/haschicups]```
````

Comment: Historically the `terraform providers` subcommand is indeed somewhat confused by locally built and loaded providers. It appears that behavior persists.

Comment: Terraform errors with "Could not load plugin" and the reason given is "configuration provided required plugins which can't be located, don't satisfy the version constraints". I am sure this error is referencing to the resource which terraform is confusing as a provider

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used an incorrect resource type name for the resource: you wrote `haschicups_order` instead of `hashicups_order`.

Because you've not declared a provider with the local name `haschicups`, Terraform is assuming that this resource type must belong to a provider named `hashicorp/haschicups`, by the same mechanism that Terraform allows declaring an `aws_instance` resource without explicitly declaring the AWS provider.

If you correct your resource type name to have the same prefix as the provider's local name then Terraform should associate the resource with the provider as you expected:

```
resource "hashicups_order" "edu" {
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 3
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 2
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I discovered it later that I need to use the provider prefix for the resource to be recognised as part of the provider. Also thanks for pointing me to the correction in provider name!